# SharePoint Framework with React Component loading images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spfx

I have an image in the same folder as my React component:

[image]

I'm trying to render it:

```
<img src="require('./incident-report-graphic.jpg')"alt="test" />
```

I get the broken image icon:

[image]

In my `gulpfile.js`, I added in the local path stuff:

```
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
    additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
        if (build.getConfig().production) {
            var basePath = build.writeManifests.taskConfig.cdnBasePath;
            if (!basePath.endsWith('/')) {
                basePath += '/';
            }
            generatedConfiguration.output.publicPath = basePath;
        }
        else {
            generatedConfiguration.output.publicPath = "/dist/";
        }
        return generatedConfiguration;
    },    
});
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

I just notice I'm getting an error:

```
GET https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/sbx/mySite/_layouts/15/require('/assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg') 404
```

EDIT 2:  I tried Matt's suggestion and change my code to:

```
<img src={require('./assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg')}alt="test" />
```

I got the error:

```
YellowCardForm.tsx:177 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module "./assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg"
```

EDIT 3:

[image]

Comment: You are passing the literal string `require('./incident-report-graphic.jpg')` as the image path, which can't be right.  Try curly braces instead of double quotes around the `require` call so the call gets evaluated.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I tried `<img src={require('./assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg')}alt="test" />` and I get `YellowCardForm.tsx:177 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module "./assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg"` error.

Comment: First, try `require('./incident-report-graphic.jpg)` without the `assets`, because I don't see an `assets` folder in your project structure.  If you still have trouble, then the problem is likely with your Webpack configuration, so please add it to the question.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen That did it.  I had the image in both locations; same folder and in the /assets folder.  How can I access the image in the /assets folder? I'll add a pic of the structure.

Comment: It looks like the correct relative path to use in `require` would be `../../assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know if it was relative path or absolute path, thanks!  If you want to put up an answer, we can get everything square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved in comments.  There were two issues:

1. The JSX code:

   ```
   <img src="require('./incident-report-graphic.jpg')"alt="test" />
   ```

   was passing the literal string `"require('./incident-report-graphic.jpg')"` as the image path.  Instead, the require call needs to be evaluated as an expression and its return value passed as the image path:

   ```
   <img src={require('./incident-report-graphic.jpg')}alt="test" />
   ```
2. The path to the image, `./assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg`, was incorrect.  The correct relative path is `../../assets/incident-report-graphic.jpg`.  It might be possible to use an absolute path, but I didn't pursue that.